# How to reduce the number of rows of a table based on another table in Oracle SQL without joining?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have an object in the database which has millions of accounts. Say there is another object which has the accounts that i need for building my report. I want to write a query that selects all from first object but only for the accounts that are in the second object.
If i write

```
select * from first f inner join second s on f.ID=s.ID
```

I'm getting the columns in second object which i don't want because there are similarly named fields in both and Tableau throws an error when i connect to it. Can someone help me with this?

Thakns

Comment: Just select the columns that you *do* want in the `select`.

Comment: Like @GordonLinoff said, specify which columns you want instead of just using asterisk.  If you want everything in the first table, do select f.* instead of just select *

Comment: What does "without joining" mean? What does "selects all from first object but only for the accounts that are in the second object" mean? Please in code questions give a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

> I want to write a query that selects all from first object but only for the accounts that are in the second object.

You've got these...

```sql
-- Object with mIlLiOns of accounts
millions

-- Object with accounts for your report
accounts_for_report
```

I'd start with something like...

```sql
SELECT mil.*
FROM millions mil INNER JOIN accounts_for_report afr
ON mil.ID = afr.ID;
```

If you wanted to accomplish this without a join (as the subject alludes), you can do this...

```
SELECT *
  FROM millions mil
 WHERE EXISTS (
         SELECT * accounts_for_report WHERE ID = mil.ID
 );
```